# compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' happened wrong: all com android support libraries must use the exact same version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Today, I update my Android studio to 2.3, and I update gradle to 3.4.1. But when I build my project, an error occurred:
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PThyX.jpg)
So I add " buildToolsVersion '25.0.0' "

My project can build successful, but another error occurred. I can't solve it. I hope to get some help. Thank you!
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bebwU.jpg)

When I add compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.2', this error will occur.
[This is my androidDependencies](https://github.com/dale311/Test/blob/master/androidDependencies)

Comment: as error says, you must use same version for all google play service libs. change it to 25.0.0

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file.

Comment: Well the error tells you what to do pretty straightforward, just use the same version for all support libraries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is probably an issue with Android Studio 2.3. There's a new inspection that checks if all dependencies of `com.android.support` use the same version number. However, `multidex` doesn't have a matching version number. You can disable the inspection via the red light bulb icon next to it as a work-around for now

Comment: Or you can use the following:

    //noinspection AndroidLintGradleCompatible
    compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"

Answer (score 7):

it's an unnecessary warning for the *support:multidex*, add this:

```
//noinspection AndroidLintGradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using updated Studio. You should use each library with the same version in order to avoid the Manifest Merger issue. Like this.

```
 // To Support Design, CardView and RecyclerView Library
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.2.0'

// To Support MultiDex
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Here you will notice that each library have the same version.

Comment: I know the mean of error, But I can not find where used different version. I used  "androidDependencies"  to find difference, but I did not find.

Comment: Can you paste your dependencies.

Comment: I have uploaded my androidDependencies.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change version of **com.android.support:recyclerview-v7** and **com.android.support:support-core-utils** to **25.2.0** (last version of support library: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)