# Android Studio Multiple Dex file dependencies defined error

Tags: android, dependencies, dex, defined

**I have been trying for a week and have never tried solutions in sites.
Error Current.**

```js
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: 
Multiple dex files define 
Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzaac$zza;
```

**Gradle codes**

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        //multiDexEnabled true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oyunlar.dortislem"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        //multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //multiDexKeepProguard 'multidex-config.pro'
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**AndroidManifest codes:**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.oyunlar.dortislem">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1"
        >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DortislemOyunu"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".DortislemOyunuSonuc"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".TopList"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".NtGirisGiris"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Admin"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you

Thanks a lot. But now the bottom error is coming out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9TEM.jpg)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You are including all Play services in your project. Only add those you want. For example, if you are using only maps, then change

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
```

From the doc:

> In versions of Google Play services prior to 6.5, you had to compile
>   the entire package of APIs into your app. In some cases, doing so made
>   it more difficult to keep the number of methods in your app (including
>   framework APIs, library methods, and your own code) under the 65,536
>   limit.
>
> From version 6.5, you can instead selectively compile Google Play
>   service APIs into your app. For example, to include only the Google
>   Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your
>   build.gradle file:
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
>
> with these lines:
>
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0' 
>   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0'

Or you can try like this in app build.gradle:

```
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

In your manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Comment: @Nurullah tayipoğlu have you tried to delete apply plugin line

Comment: I have not deleted

Comment: I have searched and that inspection doesn't affect your gradle., according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42644455/7673764)